# Can I license my specs/tests differently than my actual library/application source code?

Tags: licensing

I've written a Ruby gem that I've licensed under the MIT license, but I think I could greatly improve the test coverage by using an AGPL library in my specs.  The actual library code I've written (that would be executed by people using the gem) would never use this AGPL library, it would just be for running the tests in a development environment when running the gem specs.

Is it legal for me to then license my spec code under AGPL while still licensing my library/application code under MIT?  Is there anything special I would have to do with regard to my GitHub repository (e.g. a separate repo for the specs) or my .gemspec file (e.g. not bundling the specs and AGPL library with the gem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am not a lawyer.

Let's assume that the library you're going to use is named L.

Since your application code is not a derivative work of L it is not affected by AGPL's licensing. Therefore you're free to choose rules under which it is distributed.

Your test code is a derivative work of L in the sense of AGPL and as a result if you publish it you have to use terms of AGPL.

Storing files with different licenses in a single repository is not an issue. What is important is to clearly and unambigously state what is the license of each file. The best idea is to put relevant notes both in files' headers and a README or LICENSE file. What I mean is something like

> All files in the `test` directory are published under terms of (...). All remaining files are published under terms of (...) unless otherwise stated.

Remember to add this information in each form of distribution of your project, i.e. a gem file, a tarball and so on. If you have to specify terms under which your *whole* gem is published you have to provide both licenses. In the terms of a [gemspec](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#license) it would mean

```
spec.licenses = ['MIT', 'AGPL']
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough reply (even though apparently my question is "off topic")!